# Read in (from std in) a list of integers/ints on different lines Java

Tags: java, input, integer, java.util.scanner

How can I read in one line of integers at a time before moving on to the next one?

I'm receiving input like below (ignore bullet points):

- 4 -space- - space- 2 - space- - space- - space- 3
- -space- 84 -space -space- 6
- 2 -space- -space- -space- 8 -space- -space- 19

where for each row of integers I want to perform operations on **only that row**. Then I want to get the next row and perform operations on that one and so on.

I won't know how many spaces there are between numbers and I'm currently using Java's scanner.

Comment: you mean only read untill the integer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better way and one possible way could be reading whole line as a single string and then splitting each on spaces. These will be string though and you have to change it to integer.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scanner.nextLine();
String[] splitStr = str.split(" ");

for(String s: splitStr)
     System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've used this and my program is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with the `nextLine()` function and a `StringTokenizer` object, along with an `ArrayList<Integer[]>` to store the lines of text:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(/*input source*/);
StringTokenizer input;
ArrayList<Integer[]> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        input = new StringTokenizer(sc.nextLine());
        Integer[] n = new Integer[input.countTokens()];
        for (int i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
            n[x] = new Integer(input.nextToken());
        }
        numbers.add(n);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // do whatever you want here to handle non-integer input
}
```

This will convert each individual line into a separate `Integer` array, with each array being stored in an `ArrayList`. Alternatively, you could use an `ArrayList<String>` and parse the integer values elsewhere in the code.

Also, for a note on the `while (sc.hasNextLine())` part, you should NOT use this if your `Scanner` is reading from `System.in`, as this will result in an infinite loop. If your `Scanner` is reading from `System.in`, you should either a) have the user input a certain command to terminate the loop, or b) use a `for` loop so it takes a fixed number of input lines.